# MySQL para SQL Sever

Tags: mysql, sql

Como ficaria o seguinte código `MySQL` em `SQL Server 2008`:

```
desc `TABLE 2`;

alter table `TABLE 2` add column `COLL 44` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL;
alter table `TABLE 2` add column `COLL 45` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL;
alter table `TABLE 2` add column `COLL 46` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL;
alter table `TABLE 2` add column `COLL 47` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL;
alter table `TABLE 2` add column `COLL 48` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL;
alter table `TABLE 2` add column `COLL 49` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL;
alter table `TABLE 2` add column `COLL 50` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL;
alter table `TABLE 2` add column `COLL 51` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL;

select * from `TABLE 2`;
update `TABLE 2` AS T2
INNER JOIN `TABLE 1` AS T1 ON T1.`COL 1` = T2.`COL 1` -- N3 FILIAL
                                 AND T1.`COL 2` = T2.`COL 2` -- N3_CBASE
                                 AND T1.`COL 3` = T2.`COL 3` -- N3_ITEM
                                 AND T1.`COL 11` = T2.`COL 8` -- N3_CCDEPRE
SET
        T2.`COL 44` = T1.`COL4`, -- N3_TIPO
        T2.`COL 45` = T1.`COL8`, -- N3_CUSTOBEM
        T2.`COL 46` = T1.`COL18`, -- N3_VORIGI
        T2.`COL 47` = T1.`COL19`, -- N3_TXDEPR1
        T2.`COL 48` = T1.`COL33`, -- N3_TVRDACM1
        T2.`COL 49` = T1.`COL59`, -- N3_FIMDEPR
        T2.`COL 50` = T1.`COL79`, -- N3_CLV
        T2.`COL 58` = T1.`COL16`; -- N3_DINDEP


SELECT * 
FROM `TABLE 2` AS T2            
WHERE 
                T2.`COL 44` IS NOT NULL OR  
                T2.`COL 45` IS NOT NULL OR  
                T2.`COL 46` IS NOT NULL OR  
                T2.`COL 47` IS NOT NULL OR  
                T2.`COL 48` IS NOT NULL OR  
                T2.`COL 49` IS NOT NULL OR  
                T2.`COL 50` IS NOT NULL OR  
                T2.`COL 51` IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Você tem uma tabela com espaço no nome? Isso aí tá bem errado

Comment: @Sorack sim, subi um CSV e ele criou nome da tabela automático como TABLE 2, por isso os ` ` rodou direitinho no mysql, problema que preciso rodar em SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Em **SQL Server** seria algo deste género:

```
EXEC sp_columns [TABLE 2]

ALTER TABLE [TABLE 2] ADD [COLL 44] VARCHAR(20) NULL
ALTER TABLE [TABLE 2] ADD [COLL 45] VARCHAR(20) NULL
ALTER TABLE [TABLE 2] ADD [COLL 46] VARCHAR(20) NULL
ALTER TABLE [TABLE 2] ADD [COLL 47] VARCHAR(20) NULL
ALTER TABLE [TABLE 2] ADD [COLL 48] VARCHAR(20) NULL
ALTER TABLE [TABLE 2] ADD [COLL 49] VARCHAR(20) NULL
ALTER TABLE [TABLE 2] ADD [COLL 50] VARCHAR(20) NULL
ALTER TABLE [TABLE 2] ADD [COLL 51] VARCHAR(20) NULL

SELECT  * 
FROM    [TABLE 2]

UPDATE      T2
SET         T2.[COL 44] = T1.[COL4],    -- N3_TIPO
            T2.[COL 45] = T1.[COL8],    -- N3_CUSTOBEM
            T2.[COL 46] = T1.[COL18],   -- N3_VORIGI
            T2.[COL 47] = T1.[COL19],   -- N3_TXDEPR1
            T2.[COL 48] = T1.[COL33],   -- N3_TVRDACM1
            T2.[COL 49] = T1.[COL59],   -- N3_FIMDEPR
            T2.[COL 50] = T1.[COL79],   -- N3_CLV
            T2.[COL 58] = T1.[COL16]    -- N3_DINDEP
FROM        [TABLE 2] T2
INNER JOIN  [TABLE 1] T1 ON T1.[COL 1]  = T2.[COL 1] -- N3 FILIAL
                        AND T1.[COL 2]  = T2.[COL 2] -- N3_CBASE
                        AND T1.[COL 3]  = T2.[COL 3] -- N3_ITEM
                        AND T1.[COL 11] = T2.[COL 8] -- N3_CCDEPRE

SELECT  * 
FROM    [TABLE 2]
WHERE   [COL 44] IS NOT NULL OR 
        [COL 45] IS NOT NULL OR  
        [COL 46] IS NOT NULL OR  
        [COL 47] IS NOT NULL OR  
        [COL 48] IS NOT NULL OR  
        [COL 49] IS NOT NULL OR  
        [COL 50] IS NOT NULL OR  
        [COL 51] IS NOT NULL
```

O "segredo" é a utilização dos parêntesis retos (`[]`) para substituir a plica ou acento que o **MySQL** utiliza para permitir espaços nos nomes das tabelas e/ou colunas.

Comment: PERFEITO, funcionou corretamente!

Comment: Aproveite e dê um UP na resposta :)